# How can I get time from another server using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I need to get time from some online source - NTP server, JSON time server, or maybe event just an HTTP Header. I don't care about precision, but I do need to get time from an online source. I don't have access to any servers so I can't write any server side code.

I can't do this using HTTP Request to get the header since I guess it would be violating the same origin policy.

And I can't seem to find a way of doing it that does not involve some level of PHP or other languages - I can only use HTML/CSS/JS...nothing else!

Any ideas?

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this?

Comment: Until I get a response that I need. This is a democratic community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
.done(function(response) {
    // response = {"dateString":"2012-03-06T02:18:25+00:00"}
    console.log(response.dateString);// "2012-03-06T02:18:25+00:00"
});
```

Comment: You missed a comma in the example, I added it in

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice. Couple questions - what does the dollar sign mean? And how can I run this code on pageload?

Comment: It is a variable reference to the jQuery library, which is useful for AJAX abstracting.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a same origin policy. You can not make calls to another domain. If you could do it, I could access your email, bank accounts, etc.

If the browser supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) and the 3rd party has it enabled, you are in luck. Other than that, you should look at a JSONP service that can give you the info.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript has built-in functionality for date and time. You can get the current time like so:

```
var now = new Date();
document.write(now);
```

You can read more about using Javascript's Date object here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp