# How to get time from NTP server using jQuery / Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am searching for jquery code to get time from NTP Server and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576839/how-can-i-get-time-from-another-server-using-ajax). Just tried the code in the thread and getting current time.

I navigated to [this url](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json) and the output is:

```
{"dateString":"2013-08-14T11:24:08+01:00"}
```

Can I use any public ntp server in place of "http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json" in the code. If not briefly explain why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find a server that exposes the current time as json like that then sure you can use it, but that does not make it an NTP server (as your link suggests, you are connecting to a time API).

[NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) is a specific network protocol, mainly used to synchronize the local time on a systems internal clock over the network. It is not HTTP based and thus can not be accessed directly with jQuery.

If you only need the browsers current local time in jQuery you can just use `$.now();`