# How to get Time After button is clicked with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, time

What I want to do is get the Time of the server, the moment I click a button. This time needs to be calculated(retrieved) at the time of click, this needs to be able to be done repeatedly if needed. Currently I have tried:
PHP Code

```
<?php
function getTime(){
    $Time = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    return $Time;
}
?>
```

JS Code

```
function Funct(){
    var Time = "<?php echo json_encode(getTime()); ?>";
    console.log(Time);
}
```

HTML Code
`<button onclick="Funct()">Get Time</button>`

The problem is that when I click the button, after the first click, all of the other clicks Will not update, in fact the getTime function seems to be called when the page loads and leaves a string literal that is logged. How can I control when it calculates the Time? Thanks for the help!

Comment: is your js function attached to an on click event?

Comment: yes it is attached to the Funct Function. via an HTML button, I will update post with this small line of code.

Comment: you have a fundamental misunderstanding about server side vs client side code See [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Need to make ajax request to get server time. Not instantaneous although it is very fast

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the advice is there a way you could show me how to do this. Thanks Will give best answer, if you can.

Comment: Not hard to research how to use ajax. Tutorials for it all over the web

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576839/how-can-i-get-time-from-another-server-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<button onclick="Funct()">Get Time</button>
```

JS

```
    function Funct(){
         var data = {};
         $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'php_file.php', data: data, dataType: 'json', encode: true })
        .done(function (data) {
          console.log(data.time);
        }).fail(function (data) {
           console.log(data.responseText);
         });
    }
```

PHP

```
    <?php 
        $data['time'] = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late approval works great! I'm giving you best Answer.